# NodeJs - How to avoid relative paths with import keyword

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Per several github docs, I have tried this, although it is really for the require keyword, as the very first line in the first server file fired [index.js]:

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = 'app';
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

It didn't work. Then I read up in webpack to do this, but still it does not work:

```
resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname + '/app')),
    alias: {
        app: 'app',
        component: 'app/components',
        utility: 'app/utils'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
```

How do I avoid the endless '../../../../' as my project goes deeper as I do not want to keep doing this:

Import MyComponent from '../../../../../Whatever' ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Currently I am using quite the same solution, no 6 in [this list](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#6-the-hack).

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = __dirname;
require('module').Module._initPaths();
```

Which enables me to call all my js files by folder/filename wherever I am in my code base, e.g.

```
require('services/userService');
```

This is a quite ugly solution since it relies on a private Node.js core method, this is also a hack that might stop working on the previous or next version of node.

I also asked the [same question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-the-issue-when-require-files-in-node) with some answers.